# Why is Account Owner not always shown when merging accounts?

Tags: account, merge, record-owner

We're doing some account cleanups on our org by merging duplicate accounts.  These accounts have different Account Owners.  On the merge page, where you get to reconcile fields, sometimes the Account Owner field appears and sometimes it doesn't.

Does anyone know (or can point me to documentation) the logic around why it wouldn't always display on the merge page so I can choose who owns the merged record?

Screenshot 1 - two records, different owners, owner field shown
[image: Has Owner]

Screenshot 2 - two records, different owners, owner field not **not** shown[image: No Owner field]

Comment: can we have a screenshot of your question, it will help us other members to understand the use case

Comment: Done - use case is ensuring correct ownership of merged record

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind that Master record contains `Organization Owner` which you want to keep.

Where as in the non master it should not have because it is getting merged with Master record who will own the record which has been defined as Organization Owner.

And, non master account will move into recycle bin.

Comment: That's not actually the issue here - at this stage, I'm still selecting which one I want as the master record.  Also, why would it be displayed in some situations and not others?